# Build up a value in a list of dataframes in a cumulative manner

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

A list of data frames:

```
mylist <- diamonds %>% 
  mutate(somenum = rnorm(nrow(.))) %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  group_split %>% 
  map(~ list(dta = ., initial_val = rnorm(1)))
```

E.g. the first item in mylist:

```
mylist[1]
[[1]]
[[1]]$dta
# A tibble: 163 x 11
   carat cut   color clarity depth table price     x     y     z somenum
   <dbl> <ord> <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
 1  0.75 Fair  D     SI2      64.6    57  2848  5.74  5.72  3.7    0.302
 2  0.71 Fair  D     VS2      56.9    65  2858  5.89  5.84  3.34   0.500
 3  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      66.9    57  2885  6.02  5.9   3.99   0.179
 4  1    Fair  D     SI2      69.3    58  2974  5.96  5.87  4.1    1.25 
 5  1.01 Fair  D     SI2      64.6    56  3003  6.31  6.24  4.05  -0.731
 6  0.73 Fair  D     VS1      66      54  3047  5.56  5.66  3.7    0.758
 7  0.71 Fair  D     VS2      64.7    58  3077  5.61  5.58  3.62  -1.43 
 8  0.91 Fair  D     SI2      62.5    66  3079  6.08  6.01  3.78   0.820
 9  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      65.9    59  3205  6     5.95  3.94  -1.81 
10  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      66      58  3205  6     5.97  3.95  -0.179
# … with 153 more rows

[[1]]$initial_val
[1] 1.788348
```

The list item contains a data frame as well as a number 'initial_val'.

For each data frame in the list, I would like to mutate onto it  a new field 'cumsum_someval' that starts with the initial_val for the list item and then 'builds it up' by adding the lagged cumsum of initial_val with the rows entry for somenum. E.g. the first row, the value of `cumsum_someval` will just be the initial_val `1.788348`. But the second row of `cumsum_someval` should be `1.788348 + 0.302 = 2.090348`. Then, the 3rd row would be `2.090348 + 0.500 = 2.590348`. And so on.

Perhaps something like `purrr::map` with a custom func along the lines...?

```
myfun <- function(dta, initial_val) {
  cum_val = initial_val + dta$somenum[<rownumber here>]
}
```

Open to suggestions.

For each data frame in mylist, how can I build up this new mutated field that starts with initial_val and then progresses to sum the lag of each instance of somenum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We loop over the `list` with `map`, extract the 'dta' dataset, created the new 'cum_val', by taking the `lag` of 'somenum', specify the `default` as 'initial_val', do the `cumsum`, assign the output back to 'dta' and return the whole `list` element i.e. `.x`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(mylist, ~ {
       .x$dta <- .x$dta %>%
         mutate(cum_val = cumsum(lag(somenum, default = .x$initial_val)))
     .x

      })
```

Comment: Although, it doesn't solve my real world problem. Because of the existence of the `cumsum()` function it removes the complexity I was grapling with on my real data, where I don't need to cumsum but I do need to take initial_val, apply a custom func, take the output of that custom func for each row, maybe reasign to initial_val and repeat. I.e. the output needs to be the input to the next iteration using the custom func. THis answer is 'too good' at answering the question specifically how I've asked it. Maybe I should post a fresh one with some constraints :/

Comment: @DougFir If that is the case, you may do this with `accumulate` i.e. `accumulate(somenum, .f = yourfun,  .init = .x$initial_val)`

Comment: To rephrase, is there a way where I could be more manual, where I update the lists corresponding value of 'initial_val' for each row in the mutation? 

RE `acumulate()`. Yes, I used it before and personally just found it hard to read. Would prefer this more manual approach if it's doable, do you think?

Comment: @DougFir can you check my edited comment.  Is that the code you are looking for

Comment: Yeah this does look good actually. Thanks again, gonna try and implement this

Comment: Please consider to post as a question to undersetand it better. thanks

Comment: Putting everything I learned into good use :)

Comment: (with the right link this time) Almost as tricky as the problem itself was wording my need! I had a go over here if you have a chance to take a look, would be very grateful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68307139/accumulate-or-build-a-prediction-where-the-prediction-output-is-an-input-to-the

Comment: @DougFir Sure, I am looking into it.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is not as elegant as Arun's solution, I will dedicate it to him and also to Doug for presenting us with very good challenges every once in a while:

```
library(purrr)

mylist %>%
  map_dbl("initial_val") %>%
  map2(mylist, function(a, b) {
    b %>% imap(~ if(.y == "dta") {
      .x %>% mutate(cumsum_someval = accumulate(c(a, .x$somenum[-nrow(.x)]), `+`))
    } else {
      .x
    })
  }) %>% `[`(1)

[[1]]
[[1]]$dta
# A tibble: 163 x 12
   carat cut   color clarity depth table price     x     y     z somenum cumsum_someval
   <dbl> <ord> <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>
 1  0.75 Fair  D     SI2      64.6    57  2848  5.74  5.72  3.7   0.0684         0.0391
 2  0.71 Fair  D     VS2      56.9    65  2858  5.89  5.84  3.34  0.436          0.108 
 3  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      66.9    57  2885  6.02  5.9   3.99 -0.0591         0.543 
 4  1    Fair  D     SI2      69.3    58  2974  5.96  5.87  4.1   1.08           0.484 
 5  1.01 Fair  D     SI2      64.6    56  3003  6.31  6.24  4.05 -0.478          1.57  
 6  0.73 Fair  D     VS1      66      54  3047  5.56  5.66  3.7  -0.600          1.09  
 7  0.71 Fair  D     VS2      64.7    58  3077  5.61  5.58  3.62 -0.825          0.487 
 8  0.91 Fair  D     SI2      62.5    66  3079  6.08  6.01  3.78 -1.09          -0.338 
 9  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      65.9    59  3205  6     5.95  3.94 -0.672         -1.42  
10  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      66      58  3205  6     5.97  3.95 -0.273         -2.10  
# ... with 153 more rows

[[1]]$initial_val
[1] 0.03913573
```