# Accumulate or build a prediction where the prediction output is an input to the next item

Tags: r

Some data:

```
mydiamonds <- diamonds %>% 
  group_by(cut, color) %>% 
  mutate(cumprice = cumsum(price)) %>% 
  mutate(lag_cumprice = lag(cumprice)) %>% 
  na.omit(.)
```

A model:

```
nonsense_model <- glm(cumprice ~ depth + lag_cumprice, family = "poisson", data = mydiamonds)
```

To predict with this model, the output of the prediction is also an input, since it uses lagged data. So I cannot just use predict. Here's an attempted custom function:

```
acumPredict <- function(dta, mod, initial_amount) {
  
  # for each row in the dataframe, predict/build
  for(r in 1:nrow(dta)) {
    total_exponent <-
      mod$coefficients['(Intercept)']  +
      (mod$coefficients['depth'] * dta$depth[r]) + 
      (mod$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * initial_amount)
    predictced_cumprice = exp(total_exponent)
    #<update initial_value for the list item here with predictced_cumprice>
    return(predictced_cumprice)
  }
}
```

And, here is a list of dataframes, which is just mydiamonds split by the grouping, along with an item for the initial_value of cumulative_price:

```
mylist <- mydiamonds %>% 
  group_split %>% 
  map(~ list(dta = ., initial_val = min(.$cumprice)))
```

Now I have all the pieces. For each dataframe within mylist, I would like to mutate a new field `predicted_cumprice` that uses the function `acumPredict`. acumPredict takes as inputs the initial_amount which should start with the list items value of `initial_val` and then, on each row, accumulate or build predictions where the output of the prediction for `cumprice` is the input variable `lag_cumprice` for the next rows prediction.

I hope my post is clear, it's tricky to communicate it well.

I can visualize what I need, I just cannot code it. Put in other words, I need to update the value of `initial_val` for the list items on each iteration/row during `mutate(predicted_cumprice = acumPredict(...))` (assuming this is the 'right' approach?).

How can I do this?

Comment: Your function is kind of confusing.  Do you need `mylist[1:2] %>% map( ~ {
       .x$dta$predicted_cumprice <- acumPredict(.x$dta, mod = nonsense_model, initial_amount = .x$initial_val); .x
      })`

Comment: That looks about right yes. The hard part that I cannot see how to do is the update the value of `.x$initial_val` on each iteration

Comment: ok, I see.  You need to updated with the `[r]` as index

Comment: Exactly yes, each time the [r] index moves on to the next, the value of `initial_val` is also updated for use in that next iteration

Comment: can you check if the solution posted is the one you are looking for

Comment: I am not sure why the predictions are so high.  Is it because your model is `nonsensical` :=)

Comment: Trying this now...

Comment: Sorry, was away.  Is there any chance the function is not correct

Comment: Possibly, I'm reading it over and over and it _should_ be sound. Since cumprice is cumsum of price per group and then the df is sliced by group :/

Comment: Regarding the function I modified, it is your own function, but just updated the row of predicted_cumprice and the initial_amount as the predicted_cumprice in each step, so that in the loop initial_amount changes

Comment: e.g. I was checking manually  (starting value for initial_val is 5706 for the first list element) `unname(exp(nonsense_model$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * 5706 + nonsense_model$coefficients['depth'] * 56.9 + nonsense_model$coefficients['(Intercept)']))#
[1] 2111578`  This value gets updated as `initial_val` for the second iteration

Comment: In the second iteration it is `unname(exp(nonsense_model$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * 2111578 + nonsense_model$coefficients['depth'] * 66.9 + nonsense_model$coefficients['(Intercept)']))
[1] 2214081` which is the value I get from the function

Comment: Are you also looking to update the model parameters in each step

Comment: The model parameters should not change on each iteration, those should be static

Comment: then, please look at my manual calculation which gives the same output from the function.  There must be some issue in the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we update the values in each iteration inside the function with index as `r`,

-updated function

```
acumPredict <- function(dta, mod, initial_amount) {
  dta$predicted_cumprice <- NA_real_
  
  for(r in 1:nrow(dta)) {
    total_exponent <-
      mod$coefficients['(Intercept)']  +
      (mod$coefficients['depth'] * dta$depth[r]) + 
      (mod$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * initial_amount)
    predictced_cumprice = exp(total_exponent)    
    initial_amount <- predictced_cumprice
    dta$predicted_cumprice[r] <- predictced_cumprice
  }
  dta$predicted_cumprice
}
```

-testing

```
mylist2 <- mylist %>% 
    map( ~ {
       .x$dta$predicted_cumprice <- acumPredict(.x$dta, 
           mod = nonsense_model, initial_amount = .x$initial_val)
       .x
       })
```

-checking the ouptut

```
mylist2[1:2]
[[1]]
[[1]]$dta
# A tibble: 162 x 13
   carat cut   color clarity depth table price     x     y     z cumprice lag_cumprice predicted_cumprice
   <dbl> <ord> <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>        <int>              <dbl>
 1  0.71 Fair  D     VS2      56.9    65  2858  5.89  5.84  3.34     5706         2848           2111578.
 2  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      66.9    57  2885  6.02  5.9   3.99     8591         5706           2214081.
 3  1    Fair  D     SI2      69.3    58  2974  5.96  5.87  4.1     11565         8591           2106000.
 4  1.01 Fair  D     SI2      64.6    56  3003  6.31  6.24  4.05    14568        11565           2355904.
 5  0.73 Fair  D     VS1      66      54  3047  5.56  5.66  3.7     17615        14568           2355406.
 6  0.71 Fair  D     VS2      64.7    58  3077  5.61  5.58  3.62    20692        17615           2440519.
 7  0.91 Fair  D     SI2      62.5    66  3079  6.08  6.01  3.78    23771        20692           2625804.
 8  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      65.9    59  3205  6     5.95  3.94    26976        23771           2461070.
 9  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      66      58  3205  6     5.97  3.95    30181        26976           2393474.
10  0.9  Fair  D     SI2      64.7    54  3205  6.1   6.04  3.93    33386        30181           2454723.
# … with 152 more rows

[[1]]$initial_val
[1] 5706


[[2]]
[[2]]$dta
# A tibble: 223 x 13
   carat cut   color clarity depth table price     x     y     z cumprice lag_cumprice predicted_cumprice
   <dbl> <ord> <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>        <int>              <dbl>
 1  0.86 Fair  E     SI2      55.1    69  2757  6.45  6.33  3.52     3094          337           2217306.
 2  1.01 Fair  E     I1       64.5    58  2788  6.29  6.21  4.03     5882         3094           2402788.
 3  1.01 Fair  E     SI2      67.4    60  2797  6.19  6.05  4.13     8679         5882           2283138.
 4  0.57 Fair  E     VVS1     58.7    66  2805  5.34  5.43  3.16    11484         8679           2844474.
 5  0.96 Fair  E     SI2      53.1    63  2815  6.73  6.65  3.55    14299        11484           3611755.
 6  0.98 Fair  E     SI2      53.3    67  2855  6.82  6.74  3.61    17154        14299           4037777.
 7  1.01 Fair  E     SI2      67.6    57  2862  6.21  6.11  4.18    20016        17154           2913440.
 8  0.8  Fair  E     SI1      56.3    63  2885  6.22  6.14  3.48    22901        20016           3343916.
 9  0.71 Fair  E     VS2      64.6    59  2902  5.62  5.59  3.62    25803        22901           2845239.
10  0.9  Fair  E     SI2      65      58  2930  6.08  6.04  3.94    28733        25803           2608244.
# … with 213 more rows

[[2]]$initial_val
[1] 3094
```

-manual check for the first three values for first list element

```
> unname(exp(nonsense_model$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * 5706 + nonsense_model$coefficients['depth'] * 56.9 + nonsense_model$coefficients['(Intercept)']))
[1] 2111578
> unname(exp(nonsense_model$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * 2111578 + nonsense_model$coefficients['depth'] * 66.9 + nonsense_model$coefficients['(Intercept)']))
[1] 2214081

> unname(exp(nonsense_model$coefficients['lag_cumprice'] * 2214081 + nonsense_model$coefficients['depth'] * 69.3 + nonsense_model$coefficients['(Intercept)']))
[1] 2106000
```

Comment: Been staring at this a while and making it fit with my actual code. Something looks fundamentally flawed since predicted_cumprice should never be less than a preceeding row. In your example output above, on the first dataframe shown, the second prediction is 2214081 while the third one is 2106000. This shouldn't be, it should always be more than the previous iteration :/